# Table1() Descriptive Statistics in R

Tags: r, charts, statistics

Are there any table1 users that know how to sort a table descending by frequency? Example in the table attached do you know how to sort to 14,11,7?

```
library(table1)
mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
table1(~mtcars$cyl, data = mtcars)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to arrange the factor levels based on frequency of `cyl`.

```
mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl, levels = as.integer(names(sort(table(mtcars$cyl),
                                  decreasing = TRUE))))
table1::table1(~cyl, data = mtcars)
```

[image]

Comment: It is important to note that if you are sorting by a factor variable which is a string and not a number - you should change `as.integer` to `as.factor`